# Binary Erlang Term serializer for C#

Tags: c#, erlang, bert-rpc

Are there any BERT or BERT-RPC implementations for C#?

On the http://bert-rpc.org/ no C# implementations are listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one (written in F#, usable from C# and generally any .NET language) is called Filbert, available on Github (https://github.com/theburningmonk/Filbert) and NuGet